# array_sum return 0. How do I sum my array?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-8

I have this

```
        foreach ($item_id as $key => $no) {
            $input['price'] = $price[$key]['price'];
            $input['quantity'] = $quantity[$key];
            $subtotal[] = [$input['price']*$input['quantity']];
        }
        $total_price = array_sum($subtotal);
```

When I `dd($total_price)` it return `0`.
When I `dd($subtotal)` it return my array like this

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    0 => 3000000
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    0 => 3
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    0 => 9
  ]
]
```

How do I sum my array from that? Thanks!

Comment: Avoid adding a array to subtotal, e.g, `$subtotal[] = $input['price']*$input['quantity']` and it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this line :

```
$subtotal[] = [$input['price']*$input['quantity']];
```

you are assigning an array, which is why you end up with the structure that you see when you dd($subtotal).

Just do :

```
$subtotal[] = $input['price']*$input['quantity'];
```

and you should be fine.